# What to do if a user doesn't accept any answer even when the answer is correct

Tags: discussion, accept-rate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it okay to ask a user to accept an answer for his/her question?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1519/is-it-okay-to-ask-a-user-to-accept-an-answer-for-his-her-question)

I have come across some users who have 0% accept rate. They don't accept the answer even when the answer is helpful or correct. What to do with this type of users?

Comment: Related? -[Encouraging new users to accept answers](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2869/encouraging-new-users-to-accept-answers)

Comment: I am not talking about new users! I am talking about existing users...

Comment: @MarcoCeppi It is not a duplicate. For example a existing user has 100 rep and he has 0 % accept rate. Suppose he asked a question and someone gave him the best solution (or right solution) which helped him but he doesn't marked the answer as right....

Comment: The answer to that question is virtually the same here. Ask them to accept the answer.

Comment: The site will also show them a banner reminding them to accept answers if their AR is too low.