# Is there a way to prompt someone for an answer acceptance

Tags: feature-request, answers, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it okay to ask a user to accept an answer for his/her question?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1519/is-it-okay-to-ask-a-user-to-accept-an-answer-for-his-her-question)

When one answers a question which is confirmed as correct, is it solely up to the individual who asked the question to accept it? I feel that sometimes, a flash in the pan user which never returns leaves the answer un-accepted and denies the answer his/hers reputation. Is this just a "fact of the matter" here or is there options to claim my correct response?

Comment: This is why we encourage every one to vote, every day!