# Why does askubuntu on a whole have so many questions without accepted answers?

Tags: discussion

Why is it that AskUbuntu has so many questions that have answers that would solve the question, and have even sometimes been confirmed by the original asker as having worked, with either no upvotes or they are not accepted? Why doesn't askubuntu add a mod privilege that they are allowed to mark answers as accepted when the asker confirms in a comment that it worked? Why is there so little prompting for the asker to mark an answer as having solved their question? I have seen many people that I have had to either ask to mark it as solved and who have simply not known that the checkmark that is almost the same as the white background is the one that marks the answer as "the one".

Comment: [This](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113961/allow-mods-to-accept-answers-for-new-users-if-they-leave-a-comment-like-yes-th) has [been](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18312/moderators-accepting-answers-on-users-behalf-after-a-certain-time-period) suggested [several](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60212/allow-mod-accept-for-deleted-users) times all over SE. It was turned down each time, and will be for valid reasons. Mostly, it's because only the person with the problem can say if the answer solves his problem or not. If you think an answer is helpful, upvote it.

Comment: but sometimes the person will actually say in a comment that it worked, but not mark it as solved

Comment: basically - no. All this has been asked before: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2869/encouraging-new-users-to-accept-answers?rq=1 , http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5440/forcing-leavers-to-accept-an-answer?rq=1 , http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8416/provide-the-privilege-to-accept-the-answer , http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3034/is-there-a-way-to-prompt-someone-for-an-answer-acceptance , http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1519/is-it-okay-to-ask-a-user-to-accept-an-answer-for-his-her-question ,

Comment: then upvote and move on. If it is your answer don't worry about it - it isn't worth the 15 points. Or vote to close/flag the question "not reproducible"

Comment: sorry, I really didn't know and was just a little frustrated. 15 points is still 15 points...

Comment: `15 points is still 15 points... ` If all you are here for is useless internet points, you are here for the wrong reasons. I should also point out that asking and/or bugging people to accept answers is considered very bad practice (outside of a few circumstance) and those comments will regularly be deleted. Also, a question with an answer that has a score of 1 or more is marked as "answered" by the system.

Comment: I thought that a question that was not marked as "answered" by the asker was marked as unanswered, Ok now I understand, sorry

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any question with an answer with a positive score is considered answered by the system, regardless of the OP accepting one. By that I mean in our site-statistics and on the Unanswered tab.

If you see a question with a 0-score answer that answers the question, vote for it.
Congratulations, now you're part of the solution.

*Politely* reminding question-askers to accept answers is allowed but don't expect a 100% success rate. It's just how things work some times.

Comment: understood, I've just gotten a little frustrated when someone says that the solution solved their problem but don't mark it as "solved"