# "Prompting for accepts"?

Tags: discussion

[image]

**My question: was the comment I left not okay?**

---

Is saying, *if* my answer works, please *consider* accepting it wrong?

As requested, link: [Unable to mount Windows 10 partition; it "is in an unsafe state"](https://askubuntu.com/q/843153/518562)

Comment: No it is not, usually. Can we have a link?

Comment: @Zacharee1 - Edited.

Comment: I've replied to their comment.

Comment: I used to do that only if OP was new and said "thanks! that worked!" instead of accepting. But someone pointed out that maybe this doesn't make a very nice impression and I realised they are right and I stopped, and it feels **so** much better to not think about whether I get accepts :) But I still leave comments occasionally encouraging OP to accept *someone else's* answer if they say it worked for them.

Comment: Just to be really pedantic about it :) "if my answer works" is not a good thing to put. You should wait for confirmation it worked before asking for the accept IMO. In this case, the OP did say your answer worked, so asking for an accept is 100% fine, we need those accepts. Without any indication your answer worked, it may be a bit rude to try and push for the accept. I don't think you did anything wrong here, I think that comment was left because you asked for an accept on the question but the confirmation was on the answer, so Lightness misinterpreted your comment.

Comment: Often new users haven't read the help section and don't know about the concept on this site of "accepting" an answer, so as long as you are not pushy (I don't think you came across as pushy), I think it is fine and actually a good thing to let them know. If there are multiple answers and the user hasn't accepted any and has been gone for a while with no response, then I sometimes comment to tell them that they can accept an answer if it worked for them, and if there is more than one answer that worked for them, to then choose the best one. I also provide a link to the help section on it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The way your comment is worded is perfectly fine. In fact, it has been previously covered by [Marco Ceppi](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/1520/295286):

> As for nudging the user, there is nothing wrong with leaving a comment on the question requesting the author select an answer - or improve their original question if it's still unanswered.

Not every single new user on the site knows how Ask Ubuntu works, so giving the user suggestion ( and only a suggestion, not direct push as in "Accept mine and only mine" ) is perfectly ok.

In addition, accepting an answer is a way of communicating to others ( from OP's perspective ): "Yup, that's the thing I was looking for". It doesn't necessarily imply that it works in all cases - just for that specific person. They can sure leave an answer unaccepted to signify that the solution didn't work in their case. But when OP says "That worked ! Thanks!" , I personally see accepting an answer as way of ( at least visually ) confirming the solution works